# How to remove Warnings From our Code in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

What does  " control reaches end of non-void function" means??

How to remove the warnings from out code ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int LinearSearch()
{
    int ans=-1;
    
    cout << "Enter the Size of the array:  \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the array elements: \n";
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int key;
    cout << "Enter the key: \n";
    cin >> key;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            cout << "the " << key << " is found at index " << i << endl;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}

    int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\t Main Menu\n";
        cout << "1. For Linear Search\n";
        cout << "2. For Binary Search\n";
        cout << "3. For First and last Occurence\n";

        int ch;
        cout << "Enter the choice: \n";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
           
          cout<<  LinearSearch();
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid Choice OOps!! ";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Qxh.png)

AS I am trying to run it it is giving me Warning Why??
Error is: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
How to resolve it?

Comment: Tip: You should probably read in the array outside of `LinearSearch`, and pass it as an argument (along with its size).

Comment: Simple approach is to add a `return -1;` to the end of `LinearSearch()`  (or return some other value which indicates the function had not previously returned).    Incidentally, `int arr[n];` where `n` is a variable is NOT VALID in standard C++  (although some compilers support it as a *non-standard extension*).

Comment: "Control reaches end of non-void function" means that you've defined a (non-void) return type for the function but haven't actually returned anything. Or more correctly, it is possible that you don't return anything.

Comment: On a side note use `#include <iostream>`  instead of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (which is not standard C++) and use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int a[n]` it is a language extension. Default C++ requires `n` to be a constant. And do not use `using namespace std;` And if you use `std::vector` have a look at [range based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to learn C++ from competition sites. Save yourself a lot of time and get [a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301) to get yourself started. If you want to compete for fun or practice after learning the fundamentals, go nuts, but competition sites are not intended to teach and as a result do a terrible job.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: At the end of your function that is supposed to return something, but doesn't return something, and you don't expect the program should be able to get there, just put a `throw "never happen";` at the end of the code block.

Answer (score 0):

When `n` is zero, you never reach a `return`. You need a `return` after the loop. Returning `-1` might be the sensible choice in that situation. (Also, the `return` in the loop is misplaced...)

Answer (score 0):

It means that `int LinearSearch()` is expected to return an `int` but there are code paths where that does not happen.  For instance, if `n == 0`.  You fix this by adding a return statement with an appropriate value on that code path.  It's probably an error that you have the return within the `for()` loop as this means you get at most one iteration.  Maybe this is what you want?

```
int LinearSearch()
{
    int ans=-1;

    cout << "Enter the Size of the array:  \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the array elements: \n";
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int key;
    cout << "Enter the key: \n";
    cin >> key;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            cout << "the " << key << " is found at index " << i << endl;
            ans = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, the warning indicates one of your code path has no return value. In LinearSearch after the for loop a return is missing. You can use -1 to return when a key match is not found or better still is if your C++ compiler supports C++17 or higher standard then I would suggest using `std::optional` and to return a "no value" to use `std::nullopt` and return the "ans" when you actually find the key.
Please look at the code below for a sample implementation.

```
#include <optional>

using namespace std;

std::optional<int> LinearSearch()
{
    int ans;
    
    cout << "Enter the Size of the array:  \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the array elements: \n";
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int key;
    cout << "Enter the key: \n";
    cin >> key;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            cout << "the " << key << " is found at index " << i << endl;
            return ans;
        }
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

    int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\t Main Menu\n";
        cout << "1. For Linear Search\n";
        cout << "2. For Binary Search\n";
        cout << "3. For First and last Occurence\n";

        int ch;
        cout << "Enter the choice: \n";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:{
          auto res = LinearSearch();
          if (res) cout<<  *res;
          else cout << "key not found";
        }
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid Choice OOps!! ";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```